# SQL Server 2008 log of dropped stored procs

Tags: sql-server, syslog

I am using SQL Server 2008 and noticed that an important stored procedure was missing.

How do I find out when and by whom a stored procedure was dropped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you get location of admintrace:

```
select * from fn_trace_getinfo(NULL)
where property=2
and traceid in (1,2,3,4,5) --sometime several logs available
```

and then you check all details:

```
select DatabaseName,ObjectName,LoginName,StartTime,* 
from fn_trace_gettable('c:\path_to_log\MSSQL\Log\log_2.trc', -1)
where EventClass = 47  --Object:Deleted
```

Comment: This is fine, but don't count on it if default trace is off